# What is the order of running controller filters in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

For example, I have this in my BaseController:

```
public function __construct($module = 'basic')
{
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',create', array('on' => 'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',read', array('on' => 'get'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',update', array('on' => 'put'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',delete', array('on' => 'delete'));
}
```

If now, I would like to place another filter on POST, what would be the sequence of their execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find any documentation of the execution order, but from my own experience, they go top-down, so in case they don't manage to accept a filter, they stop the execution and that's it. So in case you keep adding filters:

```
public function __construct($module = 'basic')
{
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',create', array('on' => 'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',read', array('on' => 'get'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',update', array('on' => 'put'));
    $this->beforeFilter('cf.access:' . $module.',delete', array('on' => 'delete'));
    $this->beforeFilter('is_db_writable', array('on' => 'post')); //new entry
}
```

The system would check:

1. Do previous filters defined outside apply?
2. Can this user `cf.access:{$module}create`?
3. `Is_db_writable` at the moment?

From top of my mind, the best thing you could do is just check what is actually working. Define your own filter and return manually `false` and `true`, and log each execution.

```
public function __construct($module = 'basic')
{
    $this->beforeFilter('always_return_true', array('on' => 'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('always_return_false', array('on' => 'post'));
}
```

Did the log for the second filter appear? Then the order is top-down.

Comment: Very nice and complete explanation. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure =). But just make sure my explanation is correct in your situation

Comment: was digging through the core just now,and seems that you are completely right that they are fired from top to down. Stored as a simple array of filters, they are processed in a simple `foreach`

Comment: easygoing core, just like everything else in laravel. Pretty neat! Besides, congratulations on becoming an established user! Here are +5 more for asking something not in the documentation.